# C# Azure Service Bus Multiple Exceptions Thrown For OnMessageAsync

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, timeoutexception, faultexception

i've been implementing a listener that responds to an OnMessageAsync. This works exactly as intended but in the debug feed it continually triggers these exceptions:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
```

This set of 6 exceptions seem to trigger every minute. Does anyone know why these trigger or what exactly is causing these exceptions?

code snippet:

```
OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions
{
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 5,
    AutoComplete = false
};

QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(inboundConnectionString, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
client.OnMessageAsync(async m =>
{
    try
    {
        await ProcessMessageAsync(m);
        ...
    }
    ...
}, options);
```

AutoRenewTimeout doesn't seem to make a difference in OnMessageOptions.

Comment: Do you get them when no messages come in? I guess they are internal timeouts of service bus polling.

Comment: You're correct, this appears to only trigger when the queue is empty, so if run when the queue has count of 0, these exceptions occur immediately and then every minute after. If the queue is emptied and left a minute these exceptions will also trigger.

Comment: We also observed that. Had to ignore those exceptions in the end...

Comment: There's not much can be done about those.